# split several columns in a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to split string in the 3th column to the last column, each into two columns and the header remains with the first splitted column. 
here is the dataframe:

```
Sample  Pop     a1      a10     a100
F295    Pesche  AC      AT      AA
F296    Pesche  GT      CG      AC
F297    Pesche  AA      GG      TT
F298    Pesche  AC      AG      CG
```

and here is the dataframe that I want to have, from 3th column split to two columns (tab delimited) with the strings:

```
Sample  Pop     a1      a10     a100
F295    Pesche  A   C   A   T   A     A
F296    Pesche  G   T   C   G   A     C
F297    Pesche  A   A   G   G   T     T
F298    Pesche  A   C   A   G   C     G
```

the question is not similar to those, "split one column", please help.

Comment: Are you going to accept one of the answers below?  These people did take the time to help you with your problem.  You can show them gratitude by accepting one of the answers and up voting as many as you find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` in columns by split values by converted strings to lists with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for join together:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Sample','Pop'])
comp = [pd.DataFrame(df1[x].apply(list).values.tolist(), index=df1.index) for x in df1.columns]
df2 = pd.concat(comp, axis=1, keys=df1.columns)
print (df2)
              a1    a10    a100   
               0  1   0  1    0  1
Sample Pop                        
F295   Pesche  A  C   A  T    A  A
F296   Pesche  G  T   C  G    A  C
F297   Pesche  A  A   G  G    T  T
F298   Pesche  A  C   A  G    C  G
```

If need avoid `MultiIndex` first join columns names by f-strings for avoid duplicated columns names and then [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df2.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df2.columns]
df2 = df2.reset_index()
print (df2)
  Sample     Pop a1_0 a1_1 a10_0 a10_1 a100_0 a100_1
0   F295  Pesche    A    C     A     T      A      A
1   F296  Pesche    G    T     C     G      A      C
2   F297  Pesche    A    A     G     G      T      T
3   F298  Pesche    A    C     A     G      C      G
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Sample': ['F295','F296','F297','F298'],
    'Pop': ['Pesche', 'Pesche', 'Pesche', 'Pesche'],
    'a1': ['AC', 'GT', 'AA', 'AC'],
    'a10': ['AT', 'CG', 'GG', 'AG'],
    'a100': ['AA', 'AC', 'TT', 'CG']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data) # For reproductibiliy, you should include this kind of code in your next questions :)

for col_name in list(df.columns[2:]): # iterate on all column after the third one
    df[col_name] = df[col_name].apply(lambda x: f"{x[0]}\t{x[1]}") # split on tab

df
```